# How to check if a group of consecutive frames from a video are same not?

Tags: python, opencv, video, frame

I have a set of consecutive frames from a video. For example like this
({F1, F20}, {F34, F40}, {F89, F200}). So here from F1 to F20 represents one segment or a sequence of frames. My question is how can I know which segment has the most variability as most of the frames are quite similar in a segment. In this case, I want the second segment to be the output.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious variant is to calc pixelwise absotule difference. If you have high-resolution videos you can sacrifice accuracy for performance by downscaling frames, the overall picture should not change much because of this.

For each frame perform:

```
curr_frame =  # ... however you get it
curr_frame_downscaled = cv2.resize(curr_frame, (400, 400), cv2.INTER_AREA)
diff_index = np.sum(np.abs(curr_frame_downscaled - prev_frame_downscaled))
prev_frame_downscaled = curr_frame_downscaled
```

After this you can operate diffs as you wish e.g. find diff sum for each segment or average diff etc. You can also test different color spaces but keep in mind they can have different value ranges among channels, so some of them require normalization.

I don't know anything about your segments though. Video where each frame swaps white and black screens will be considered as extremely different in spite of there are only two frame states. In this way try to sort frames with `np.diff()` before.